# Build Server Hardware Configuration

Tags: build-process, continuous-integration

So I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184940/recommended-spec-for-a-build-server), but I'm looking for some more general advice: **How do you spec out a build server?** Specifically what steps should I take to decide exactly what processor, HD, RAM, etc. to use for a new build server. What factors should I consider to decide whether to use virtualization?

I'm looking for general steps I need to take to come to the decision of what hardware to buy. Steps that lead me to specific conclusions - think "I will need 4 gigs of ram" instead of "As much RAM as you can afford"

P.S. I'm deliberately not giving specifics because I'm looking for the teach-a-man-to-fish answer, not an answer that will only apply to my situation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is what requirements will the machine need in order to "build" your code. That is entirely dependent on the code you're talking about.

If its a few thousand lines of code then just pull that old desktop out of the closet. If its a few billion lines of code then speak to the bank manager about giving you a loan for a blade enclosure!

I think the best place to start with a build server though is buy yourself a new developer machine and then rebuild your old one to be your build server.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by collecting some performance metrics on the build on whatever system you currently use to build.  I would specifically look at CPU and memory utilization, the amount of data read and written from disk, and the amount of network traffic (if any) generated.  On Windows you can use perfmon to get all of this data; on Linux, you can use tools like vmstat, iostat and top.  Figure out where the bottlenecks are -- is your build CPU bound?  Disk bound?  Starved for RAM?  The answers to these questions will guide your purchase decision -- if your build hammers the CPU but generates relatively little data, putting in a screaming SCSI-based RAID disk is a waste of money.

You may want to try running your build with varying levels of parallelism as you collect these metrics as well.  If you're using gnumake, run your build with `-j 2`, `-j 4` and `-j 8`.  This will help you see if the build is CPU or disk limited.

Also consider the possibility that the right build server for your needs might actually be a cluster of cheap systems rather than a single massive box -- there are lots of distributed build systems out there (gmake/distcc, pvmgmake, ElectricAccelerator, etc) that can help you leverage an array of cheap computers better than you could a single big system.

Answer (score 2):

Things to consider:
How many projects are going to be expected to build simultaneously?  Is it acceptable for one project to wait while another finishes?

Are you going to do CI or scheduled builds?

How long do your builds normally take?

What build software are you using?

Most web projects are small enough (build times under 5 minutes) that buying a large server just doesn't make sense.

As an example,
We have about 20 devs actively working on 6 different projects.  We are using a single TFS Build server running CI for all of the projects.  They are set to build on every check in.

All of our projects build in under 3 minutes.

The build server is a single quad core with 4GB of ram.  The primary reason we use it is to performance dev and staging builds for QA.  Once a build completes, that application is auto deployed to the appropriate server(s).  It is also responsible for running unit and web tests against those projects.

The type of build software you use is very important.  TFS can take advantage of each core to parallel build projects within a solution.  If your build software can't do that, then you might investigate having multiple build servers depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Our shop supports 16 products that range from a few thousands of lines of code to hundreds of thousands of lines (maybe a million+ at this point).  We use 3 HP servers (about 5 years old), dual quad core with 10GB of RAM.  The disks are 7200 RPM SCSI drives.  All compiled via msbuild on the command line with the parallel compilations enabled.

With that setup, our biggest bottleneck by far is the disk I/O.  We will completely wipe our source code and re-checkout on every build, and the delete and checkout times are really slow.  The compilation and publishing times are slow as well.  The CPU and RAM are not remotely taxed.

I am in the process of refreshing these servers, so I am going the route of workstation class machines, go with 4 instead of 3, and replacing the SCSI drives with the best/fastest SSDs I can afford.  If you have a setup similar to this, then disk I/O should be a consideration.